# Как добавить новые элементы в существующий xml файл

Tags: java, xml, парсер, dom

Вот мой код, который записывает xml

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBulder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();


//root mainElement
Document doc = docBulder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("Books");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

//root Book
Element Book = doc.createElement("Book");
rootElement.appendChild(Book);

//setting ganre for a book
Attr att = doc.createAttribute("ganre");
att.setValue(ganre);
Book.setAttributeNode(att);

//book id
Element bookId = doc.createElement("bookId");
bookId.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(randomString(4)));
Book.appendChild(bookId);

//bookname element
Element bookname = doc.createElement("bookName");
bookname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(name));
Book.appendChild(bookname);

//book author
Element bookAuthor = doc.createElement("bookAuthor");
bookAuthor.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(author));
Book.appendChild(bookAuthor);

//book year
Element bookYear = doc.createElement("bookYear");
bookYear.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(year)));
Book.appendChild(bookYear);

//book available
Element bookAvail = doc.createElement("bookAvailable");
bookAvail.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(free)));
Book.appendChild(bookAvail);

//write in a XMLFile
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("Test/Books.xml"));

transformer.transform(source, result);

System.out.println("File saved!");
```

Так я пытаюсь добавить новые элементы

```
File fXmlFile = new File("Test/Books.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);

Node books = doc.getFirstChild();


Element newBook = doc.createElement("Book");

[тут начинаются проблемы]
```

По итогу я хочу переписать файл примерно так:

```
<Books>
  <Book ganre="fantasy">
    <bookId>7111</bookId>
    <bookName>Tron</bookName>
    <bookAuthor>Brawm</bookAuthor>
    <bookYear>15</bookYear>
    <bookAvailable>true</bookAvailable>
  </Book>

  <Book ganre="action">
    <bookId>312</bookId>
    <bookName>Corn</bookName>
    <bookAuthor>Down</bookAuthor>
    <bookYear>23</bookYear>
    <bookAvailable>false</bookAvailable>
  </Book>
</Books>
```

Единственное, чего я добился, это обновление существующего элемента или полностью ломаю файл. Буду рад помощи.